# open ajax page from within an ajax page

Tags: ajax

We have done a site, that loads content into a div, using ajax. My question is, within that ajax page, can I initiate a new page to load onclick in the existing pages place.

So as it stands on my index page I have:

```
<section id="mycontent">

</section>
```

Onclick of a element my content gets loaded into the above section. Like so:

```
<span class="link_wrap" data-link="prices"><span class="link_title">Our Prices</span</span>
```

So on click of the above, our js pulls in the relevant page: prices.php

In the JS I have:

```
case 'prices' :

     myFunctionAjax('prices.php', function () {

         _self._focustitle();

     });

break;
```

So what I would like to do is, in say the prices.php page have a link to say deals.php

That onclick, similar to above, loads IN PLACE of prices.php content the new content from deals.php.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Adding a link with `data-link="deals"`and a `case 'deals':` does not work?

Comment: No I think because we are not "binding" to a tabgible element, as ajax has already been fired. That was the first thing I tried, didnt know wether, target self could be implemented.

Comment: Then we would need to see more code on how the logic actually works.

Comment: http://inspectorpool.com.au is the functional site